# .NET 6 - msbuild takes wrong SDK on VS2022 for Mac

Tags: macos, visual-studio, asp.net-core, .net-6.0

I get an NETSDK1045 error on Visual Studio 2022 for Mac (both, Stable and 17.3 preview version) when I try to build my netcore webapp project with .NET 6.0.

Even though I set the target framework to 6.0, Visual Studio calls dotnet sdk 5.0 msbuild

> /usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/**5.0.408**/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.NET.TargetFrameworkInference.targets(141,5): error NETSDK1045: Das aktuelle .NET SDK unterstützt .NET 6.0 nicht als Ziel. Geben Sie entweder .NET 5.0 oder niedriger als Ziel an, oder verwenden Sie eine .NET SDK-Version, die .NET 6.0 unterstützt.
> 0 Warnung(en)
> 1 Fehler

Project File:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <CopyRefAssembliesToPublishDirectory>false</CopyRefAssembliesToPublishDirectory>
</PropertyGroup>
```

The runtimes are installed if I call dotnet on the command line:

```
[/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
    Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 5.0.6 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
    Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 5.0.11 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
    Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 5.0.15 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
    Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 5.0.16 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
    Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 5.0.17 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
    Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 6.0.5 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
    Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 6.0.6 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
    Microsoft.NETCore.App 5.0.0 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]
    Microsoft.NETCore.App 5.0.6 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]
    Microsoft.NETCore.App 5.0.11 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]
    Microsoft.NETCore.App 5.0.15 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]
    Microsoft.NETCore.App 5.0.16 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]
    Microsoft.NETCore.App 5.0.17 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]
    Microsoft.NETCore.App 6.0.5 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]
    Microsoft.NETCore.App 6.0.6 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]
```

as well as the SDKs

```
5.0.402 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk]
5.0.406 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk]
5.0.407 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk]
5.0.408 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk]
6.0.300 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk]
6.0.301 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk]
```

How can I force visual studio to call msbuild of the .net6 sdk?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Use a global.json file

Create a file named `global.json` in the root of your project folder (where the solution file is or even one level above, depending on your folder structure). It's contents should be something like

```
{
  "sdk": {
    "version": "6.0.301"
  }
}
```

The version should be the SDK version you want to build with (not the runtime version).

Visual Studio may need a restart after you have created this file to work correctly.

Comment: ok - did that. 

Seems I now get a different error when the packages should be loaded.

/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/6.0.301/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.ImportWorkloads.props(14,38) : error MSB4236: Das angegebene SDK "Microsoft.NET.SDK.WorkloadAutoImportPropsLocator" wurde nicht gefunden.

Comment: ok - fixed that too. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72441492/vs-2022-for-mac-arm-64-v-17-0-installs-with-incompatible-msbuild-version helped, I had to uncheck "build with msbuild on mono".

Comment: This didnt resolve it for me, still get visual studio attempting to use 5.0.408 SDK. My situation is the same as it is for slb, except the global.json does not help. Visual Studio ignores it. I've even tried creating one at the project level as well as the root level, specifying both 6.0.300 and 6.0.400 - neither work, and VS still uses 5.0.408.

dotnet --list-sdks
5.0.100 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk]
5.0.408 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk]
6.0.300 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk]
6.0.400 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk]

Comment: @whendon Do you use a build tool that lets you build from the command line? If so, try that and try whether that gives a different result. One possible cause is that the project uses a local installation of dotnet (typical for projects that also run in CI). Otherwise, it seems something with your installation is broken.

Comment: I encounter the same issue and I tried to add the `global.json` from the .Net CLI and directly from Visual Studio, but this didn't change anything. Does it work for Web projects? Is there another parameter to add?

Comment: @Gold.strike I have never worked with web projects, but I would assume it works the same. The SDK is determined before the compiler is even invoked, so this should have an effect. Check whether building from the command line does the same as building from within VS.

Comment: I don't have any problem if I build with the .NET CLI

Comment: @Gold.strike Then you need to make sure you have the correct .NET version globally installed. Run the .NET installer for the SDK version you want.  And you might need to add `"rollforward":"minor"` to the global.json, in case you have a newer version installed.

Comment: I have a lot of SDK versions, including .NET6 (6.0.300, 6.0.302, 6.0.400, 6.0.401). I've tried by adding this new parameter in the `global.json` but the result is still the same.

Comment: Weird, this should work. Maybe you create a new question with the details of your problem. Comments are not ideal to try to track down a specific problem.

Comment: I already created a new [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73911473/visual-studio-for-mac-2022-does-not-use-expected-net6-sdk) but I didn't get any reply.